# Slow response of MVC 3.0 hosted on IIS 7/Windows 2008R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have created a mvc 3.o application and hosted on IIS7/Windows Server 2008R2, There are no major thing in application start and in global.ascx. This taking appc 5-7 seconds in first start. When I tried using JetBrains profiler, I got the method "System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.GetAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String, IApplicationHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters)" taking appx 6000 MS for single call.

So please suggest me how can I resolve this issue ?

Thanks,

Laxmilal Menaria

Answer (score 3):

You could try activating the [AutoStart feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).